# How to have a UIPageView on top of a blur effect?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on an app where I want to have a UIPageView on top of a blur effect. I know how to do it with storyboard, but since I am adding it on top of another view as a subview, I don't see a way to do it. Can anyone help me with this? The code I used to create the blur effect is like this:

```
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Answer (score 1):

actually you can use this method:

```
self.view.insertSubview(blurView, belowSubview:pageView)
```

right now page view on top of a blur.